# inner join creating a duplicate column

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, inner-join

I have two tables both containing the column artistid. When I use inner join to combine the two tables I get a resulting table that contains the column artistid twice making me unable to retrieve the artistid (as it complains about being ambiguous). How do I make sure the same column doesn't reappear after combining the tables?
This is the query I used:

```
SELECT * FROM artist a INNER JOIN track b ON a.artistid = b.artistid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only duplicate column is `artistid` (column that you use for joining) you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artist  
JOIN track USING(artistid);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9347e/1/0)**</kbd>

Otherwise you need to specify all column and add aliases if needed:

```
SELECT a.col1 AS alias, a.col2, ..., b.col1 AS alias2, b.col2, ... 
FROM artist a 
INNER JOIN track b ON a.artistid = b.artistid
```

Answer (score -1):

please do not use inner join. I had the similar problem creating report. Use instead. 
SELECT track from atrist where a.artistid = b.artistid